# Google Mapi api integrate to search my stores only

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, location

I want to integrate google map into my website which locate only my stores from city typed by visitors.

For example, let's say i'm integrating for kfc. so if any visitor enters any city it will locate all the kfc store location in that city.

I seached into google, but too confused which api and how to integrate? I found map api, places api, map api for business, etc..

Please guide me I want something like this http://www.kfc.com/storelocator/ using google map.

Comment: FYI : The map in the link is not a google map, but a Bing map http://www.microsoft.com/maps/

Comment: yes I know, that is the reason I specified in last line that "I want something like this in google map".